# Richfaces tag a4j:support ajax call not occuring in firefox 22/safari , but happening in IE8 and Google Chrome 28. Used richfaces-3.2.0.GA

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, jsf, firefox, richfaces

In my project , in a portion I need to invoke a managed bean's method asynchronously.

Here is the sample from my .xhtml

```
<h:outputLink value="#{menu.menuURL}" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">
<h:outputText value="#{menu.menuName}" />                                                                                                                               
<a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{searchBean.clickedLink}" onsubmit="setSelectSalesPerson();"
reRender="addSubscriberPanelCards,errorDetails">
    <f:param id="menuId" name="menuId" value="#{menu.menuId}" />
    <f:param id="menuUrl" name="menuUrl" value="#{menu.menuURL}" />
</a4j:support>
<a4j:support event="oncomplete" reRender="sales_person_disabled,sales_person" />
</h:outputLink>
```

The call to **searchBean.clickedLink** is perfectly happening in IE8/Chrome but for Firefox and Safari its not happening.

I am using richfaces-3.2.0.GA as the JSF implementation.

Here is the code of the bean and the method. The Bean is session managed in **faces-config.xml**

```
public void clickedLink() throws WebBaseException {
        //WEBLOGGER.debug("FacesUtils.getMenuId() before link click->"
                //+ FacesUtils.getMenuId());
        WEBLOGGER.info("***INSIDE CLICKED LINK***");}
```

How can I solve this issue, please help. Also please tell me , what are my options.

Comment: Are there any errors in Firefox Java Script error console?

Comment: There are no errors in firefox console. I have compared the dynamic javascripts generated in all the browsers. They are same.